# Get results from mssql stored procedure with jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have quite complex stored procedure in MSSQL database that returns no value (just default integer code) and has `select` statement that produces single string (`'OK'` or error message).

I can see this result in Management Studio's *Results* tab executing procedure with `exec my_procedure 'param1', 'param2'`. However, when I try to execute this query with jdbc `boolean resultExist = preparedStatement.execute(sqlString)`, I get my `resultExist` variable set to `false` and no result set is available.

Is there any way to obtain result produced by stored procedure without changing it?

Comment: have you tried debugging your code to see what result is returned after execution of stored procedure?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara Yes, I have, and initial ResultSet is always null.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures can return multiple ResultSets. See [here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-retrieve-multiple-result-sets-from-a-stored-procedure-in-jdbc/172) for sample code to access all ResultSets.

Comment: What's your sproc look like? Does it have output parameters? If so you might need to use CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(...)

Comment: no, it doesn't have any output parameters, just the statement `select @MSG as [result]`, which is considered as a result tuple by MS Server, but not by JDBC.

Comment: Can [squlrrel sql](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) see the resultset? If so, it can be accessed via jdbc.